# Change Notification from DispatcherTimer

Tags: c#, timer, inotifypropertychanged

Just when I thought I finally had a grasp on WPF change notification, some bugger of Timer destroyed my illusions...

```
public MyModel _objectToRefresh;

public Refresher(MyModel objectToRefresh,Dispatcher dispatcher)
{
    _objectToRefresh= objectToRefresh;
    _objectToRefresh.DisplayMessage = "ChangeNotification works for this one!";

    _timer = new DispatcherTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
                                DispatcherPriority.Background,
                                eh,
                                dispatcher);
    _timer.Start();
}

private void eh(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _objectToRefresh.DisplayMessage = "This Change will not show in the UI";
}
```

As a side note, `MyModel` implements INotifyPropertyChanged. Now, what was that with DispatcherTimer running on the UI thread? Can anyone explain what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found it now. To explain it, I'll have to go into detail about the use case, which I find a little hard.

I'll try to put it simple: My Bindings relate to Properties at high level, but actually I change properties further down the tree (which are evaluated by code, not binding). That's why nobody cares about the change notification :-(

Answer (score 1):

Depends. If your timer is not get called on the UI thread, then you probably pass in the wrong dispatcher. You need to pass in the UI dispatcher if you want the timer function to run on the UI thread.

Comment: It's set via `Application.Current.Dispatcher`, so it's the UI dispatcher.

Answer (score 1):

Not only `MyModel` needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but the setter of `DisplayMessage` has to fire `PropertyChanged` events.

```
String displayMessage;    
public String DisplayMessage {
      get { return displayMessage; }
      set { if (value != displayMessage) {
              displayMessage = value;
              PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DisplayMessage"));
            }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please take a look at the code sample. ChangeNotification is implemented correctly, it works from outside the timer.

Comment: It may work if set before the binding. Please show your DisplayMessage implementation.

Comment: It's a bit complex, I'll compose an example and post the link